# WordPress server keeps running out of memory and crashing, how can I determine and fix the cause?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, apache, ubuntu

In the last month my server just started blowing up randomly. I had a perfect installation that worked flawlessly for 9 months but in the last month the load and memory usage just randomly start spiraling out of control.

It appears that something external causes this to happen but I have no idea what it could be. Rebooting the server will make it run normally for anywhere from a few minutes to 18-24 hours but that's about the max.

The memory usage just keeps going up and up and up until the Apache process core dumps. The load spirals up to 20+.

[Tue Jan 05 11:31:22.629436 2016] [core:notice] [pid 1246] AH00052: child pid 8127 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)

For 9 months prior to this this server operated flawlessly with loads [in top] ranging from .01 - .20.

The server is running digital ocean's one click WordPress installation image, it has 1 GB of memory and 1 GB swap file.

My list of active plugins is as follows: Blubrry PowerPress, CloudFlare, Disqus Comment System, Jetpack,
Login LockDown, Monarch Plugin (Share On Theme123.Net),
Nofollow Links, TinyMCE Advanced, Yoast SEO

None of the plugins have been changed in many months.

My server is running only one WordPress installation and one site. WordPress and plugins are always updated to the latest version. There are no major modifications on the site.

I have had problems in the past 100% on every WordPress installation with the sites being crashed via brute force hacking attempts to /xmlrpc.php I have had to completely deny access to that even though it screws up jetpack because I have not been able to get Order Allow,Deny to work. It either causes 520's to all URLs across the whole server or it reports "order not allowed here" in the error log and it doesn't work. This is a separate issue but I would be very grateful if anyone can explain that one either. Past experience indicates leaving xmlrpc.php open to the public will result in crashed sites 100% of the time.

Can anyone help? I'm getting really desperate here this is destroying my site. Haven't been able to keep it online for more than 24 hours since early December. Nobody has any answers.

Comment: Does your site include alot of heavy images ?

Comment: Hi Kirk, I've got cloudflare on and everything turned up to the max as far as caching goes. I will try this plugin.  DP EN - My site is not super image heavy but in any case cloudflare would be caching that.  I know the cache is working and working well because I see in the cloudflare stats that cloudflare is saving more than 50% of total bandwidth (51%) and way more than 50% of requests (61%) Thanks.

Comment: I've added the Query Monitor Plugin. So far it only detected one slow query. I suspect there will be plenty of slow queries later but I think this is a symptom rather than a cause of what eats up all the memory. Once it starts swapping and consuming all the memory everything will be slow. I think it's Apache not MySQL that is making it crash and burn. Anything special I should look for in this plugin? Thanks.

Comment: So far every so often it just detects this query: `1 SELECT option_name, option_value
FROM wp_options
WHERE autoload = 'yes' 
wp_load_alloptions()
 wp-includes/option.php:181
+
 Core  519  0.0287` as slow. Most other queries are 0.0001 with occassionally a 0.0010 or 0.0012.

Comment: @KirkBeard Thanks for your input.

Comment: Can you dump your apache log? That would really help be more sure.

Comment: @AlexanderKleinhans I gave up on it.  Couldn't fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Does your site include alot of images ??

```
##EXCEED MEMORYT LIMIT 
    php_value upload_max_filesize 1000M
    php_value post_max_size 3000M
    php_value memory_limit 9999999999M
    php_value max_execution_time 999
    php_value max_input_time 999
```

Try Adding the above code into your .htaccess file in the wordpress root. This should help if your browser is crashing and giving memory dump errors. Hope this helps.

Comment: It's not the browser crashing it's apache that's crashing.  Is this still relevant? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

if your PHP process using high memory and CPU on your server then I will suggest you please try with PHP-FPM with mpm event modules. You will get better performance with this setup. Once this setup is completed you can install some cache plugins for your word press site.

Comment: I'll try. My site is already heavily cached using CloudFlare and until recently I've found this works way better than fooling around with caching plugins which are notoriously hard to configure and often interfere with other plugins.

Answer (score 0):

According to my experience Jetpack plugin uses more resources. You can try it by deactivating.

Comment: OK, but it worked for 9 months without a single issue. I have used Jetpack on every site I've ever setup without problems (at least 20 other WordPress installs).